# Modified Balls in Bins allowing " Negative Number of Balls"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a well-known formula used to count the number of solutions to:

$ x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n $ where $x_1,x_2,...,x_k $ are non-negative integers.

I would like to know if there is a known formula to count the number of solutions to

$x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n$ when $ -\infty <m  < x_1,x_2,...,x_k,n <M < \infty ; x_i 
\in \mathbb Z$, i.e., the $x_i$

are allowed to be negative integers, but are bounded above and below?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. The idea is similar to the bijection between $\geq 0$ and $\geq 1$ restriction cases.

Suppose we want to find

$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k=-6$ where $x_i\geq -3$

We add $4$ to each term to get $y_i=x_i+4$

$y_1+y_2+...+y_k=4k-6$ where each $y_i\geq 1$

There exist a bijection between solutions of $x$ and $y$.

Now the number of solutions is thus ${4k-7\choose k-1}$

Comment: Nice and clear, thanks.